# Can I Use the same certificate for Token Security and Protocol Security in SAML2?

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, saml-2.0

Can I use the same certificate issued by a certificate authority to sign the security token of **SAML** assertion and also for **HTTPS SSL on IIS**?

I am using **ColdFusion** to create the SAML Response and used **Java Keytool** to create the certifcate.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I haven't tried it. We are in the process of purchasing the Certificate(s) and was wondering if one can be used for both. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you? Yes. **Should** you? No. It's better to use a self - signed cert than to share them. I can't tell you the number of times I've seen an admin screw up and send out their private key for their HTTPS cert.